# There is a file with constantly changing name in the start up folder windows 10

Tags: windows, virus

I wanted to add a file to my startup folder, I went to my `startup` folder and discovered that a file is constantly changing its name and whenever I delete the file it generates itself back with another name. The file's original location is in that folder, it is an application (.exe) file.

Is it some shot of virus, or some system file or something else?

> **Update**
>
> Probably it is a virus as per the response and help I got.
> since, it regenerates itself after it is deleted is there any other way to delete this file rather than reinstalling the windows

Here are some snaps of that file:

[image: Image one]

[image: Image two]

[image: Image three]

[image: Image four]

Comment: almost definitely a virus. No one is ever making their exe file's icon the same as an ini file. That's why one should never hide file extensions

Comment: I would format and reinstall the system. You can't get rid of that shit.

Comment: any other way to remove this virus,  i am recently installed the windows in my laptop although installing new one is not a pain but i do need to transfer my huge files and documents.

Comment: @phuclv  thanks for the support please upvote the question so that this question could reach to more people.